# Control how android kills my app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have an android application with a lot of activities and services. If I open another application while my application is running and android needs resources kills my application and I receive NullPointerException error messages like this:

```
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{icg.android.start/icg.android.web.CustomWebActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at icg.guice.Dependencies.injectDependencies(Dependencies.java:238)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at icg.guice.GuiceActivity.<init>(GuiceActivity.java:9)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at icg.android.web.CustomWebActivity.<init>(CustomWebActivity.java:16)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
07-08 18:14:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(16300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
```

I tried to detect if android kills my activities but searching I found that there is no way to do that.

At least, is possible avoid to show the error message on the device screen? I prefer that the application crashes silently.

Thanks

Comment: If you see a null pointer exception, you have a programming error and you need to fix it.  That is not Android shutting you down, you're crashing.  You don't post enough info to solve it for you.  Post your full logcat.

Comment: I see the null pointer if the system kills my app. If I close the app all is ok.

Comment: The `onPause()` method is always called as long as Android doesn't murder your application violently (e.g. Pull the battery out), so you can use it to clean up the app in case it gets killed.

Comment: as @josh says!! you can use the onPause() method... and also you should check each  one of your services... because one of them is not finishing it's work properly... I recomend you to use the method onDestroy() to manage when your service is shutted down by android

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to stop Android from killing your services/process if it is in need of more resources. In that case you need to use the onPause() and onDestroy() methods to shut down any services that you may not need and to release as many resources back to Android as possible.

Then you have to utilize onResume() to ensure that the proper activities/services are present when the application is in focus. This might help eliminate the NullPointerException and crashing.